# Console.log error in Brackets

Tags: javascript, console.log

Every time i try to use console.log i get this kind of error.

> ERROR: Unexpected console statement. [no-console] console.log(name + '
>   is a ' + age + ' years old ' + job + ' who is married ' + isMarried +
>   ' . '); 36     ERROR: 'console' is not defined.
>   [no-undef]    console.log(name + ' is a ' + age + ' years old ' + job + '
>   who is married ' + isMarried + ' . '); 44  ERROR: Unexpected console
>   statement. [no-console]   console.log(name + ' is a ' + age + ' years
>   old ' + job + ' who is married ' + isMarried + ' . '); 44  ERROR:
>   'console' is not defined. [no-undef]  console.log(name + ' is a ' + age
>   + ' years old ' + job + ' who is married ' + isMarried + ' . ');

What will be the error on this lines

[Error Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRJR7.png)

Comment: Which browser are you testing this?

Comment: I dont know but your console is not initialised . You can use temporary solution `window.console.log()`

Comment: i'm using Brackets to run the javascript codes

Comment: You can check a documentation of ESlint plugin for Brackets [here](https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-eslint) and disable this rule, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to make change to .eslintrc file then
add these two lines to disable it completely in the whole .js file:

`/*global console*/
/* eslint no-console: "off" */`

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the console error i see that this is related to the `ESLint` so to prevent ESLint rules on console at global level you can add this rule on `rules` object of your `.eslintrc.json`

```
"rules": {
    ...,
    "no-console": ["warning"],
    ...
}
```

Or for specific line of `console` you can use `/*eslint-disable*/` just above that line, like this

```
/*eslint-disable*/
console.log('some text'); 

/*eslint-enable*/     //this will now enable eslint rules that follows this
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [ESlint](https://eslint.org/) error for not using console.

You can disable it by changing [this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) rule.

For specific line you can disable it with a comment:

```
console.log('test') // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

For the next line, it can be disabled with comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
```

Comment: In the editor preferences , which place should we disable the es-lint option ?

Comment: You can check [here](https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-eslint).

Answer (score -1):

You can also change the default by going to the Brackets extension manager and scrolling down to ESLint and disable there for all files.

[extension manager button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqyaF.png)

[extensions window with disable button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl71Q.png)