# ERROR: 'console is not defined. [no-undef] - Brackets

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I've installed brackets and currently playing around with variables and functions. All the outputs work fine in the console, however I keep getting this error in the editor.

[image: ERROR: 'Console' is not defined (no-undef)]

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console.log error in Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124988/console-log-error-in-brackets)

Comment: I think it is a typo. Use console.log instead of Console.log

Answer (score 116):

The `no-undef` rule looks out for undefined variable, without any initial assumption on the environment and the global variables (`console` for instance).

You can specify that you are in an environment where `console` indeed exists, by adding `browser` and/or `node` envs in your `.eslintrc`:

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
```

More info in the [rule doc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef#environments)

Comment: Thanks! Although I don't want to commit any `console.log`'s in the app, it's nice to at least not have the error saying "console is undefined" while debugging small things.

Answer (score 7):

just to have comment:

```
/*global console*/
```

as the first line of your .js file, and then have:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-console
```

at the line of the `console.log("");`

this will make the error go away!

Comment: or you can add these two lines to disable it completely in the whole .js file:
/*global console*/
/* eslint no-console: "off" */

Answer (score 4):

Since you have it as a Capitol `C`, I would guess that the editor thinks you're looking for a function or class. Try lowering it from `Console.log()` to `console.log("john won...")` and see if that works.

Answer (score 4):

I assume it's coming from [no-console](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) rule, which disallows calls to methods of the `console` object.

> In JavaScript that is designed to be executed in the browser, it’s
>   considered a best practice to avoid using methods on `console`. Such
>   messages are considered to be for debugging purposes and therefore not
>   suitable to ship to the client. In general, calls using `console` should
>   be stripped before being pushed to production.

Examples of correct code for this rule:

```
/*eslint no-console: "error"*/

// custom console Console.log("Hello world!");
```

As a solution, you can add this to your set of rules in `.eslintrc`

```
rules: {
    'no-console': 'off'
}
```

Comment: It seems to explicitly come from the `no-undef` rule, I don't think disabling `no-console` would help.

Answer (score 3):

This one was driving me crazy as well. You can edit Brackets' config JSON. It will remove the error icon from the left gutter:

```
{
  "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": false
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-eslint/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

add 'no-console' in rules object is inactive

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Amaury Liet's answer works with the old configuration system in ESLint; it doesn't work with the [new configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) introduced in v8.21.0 (which will become mandatory in v9).

Here's the modern way of solving this problem:

```js
// eslint.config.js
import js from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";

export default [
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["src/**/*.js"],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.node,
      },
    },
  // ...
}
```

The idea is to use the [`globals`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals) package and pass it to the [`languageOptions.globals`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#configuring-global-variables) setting option in the new configuration file `eslint.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

With eslint's [new config system](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) (the one that uses the `eslint.config.js` file), you should use the following code snipet:

```
import globals from "globals";

export default [
    {
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
            }
        }
    }
];
```

This has been described in the following blog: [ESLint's new config system, Part 2](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#goodbye-environments%2C-hello-globals)

Comment: Isn't this the exact same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75822767/4883195)?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should write "`console.log`" instead of "`Console.log`". It should be lowecase.

Answer (score -3):

This might seem like a special case, but deleting and recreating the .eslintrc file fixed this issue for me.